# LibGdx / JAVA addlistener to a class

Tags: java, android, libgdx

currently I manually add InputListener to each of the image.

something like code below:

```
    grid1 = new Image(gridTex1);
    grid2 = new Image(gridTex2);
    grid3 = new Image(gridTex3);
    grid4 = new Image(gridTex4);
    grid5 = new Image(gridTex5);


    grid1.addListener(new InputListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            //doSomething
            return true;
        }
    });
    grid2.addListener(new InputListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            //doSomething
            return true;
        }
    });
    grid3.addListener(new InputListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            //doSomething
            return true;
        }
    });
    grid4.addListener(new InputListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            //doSomething
            return true;
        }
    });
    grid5.addListener(new InputListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            //doSomething
            return true;
        }
    });
```

If i have 200 image and each of it I want to have InputListener i dont think this is the way.

so, what I plan to do is create a class let say "Grid",
this class have InputListener that will return the value inside that class.
then I can store this class in array with all member of it has inputListener.

Maybe this is the wrong way too, please give me some guide. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

An instance of [`InputEvent`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/InputEvent.html) allows to get the [related actor](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/InputEvent.html#getRelatedActor--) -- albeit this is only valid for the `enter` and `exit` events. So it should be possible to have a class that tracks the current image that has been entered, and then use that image during the `touchDown` event.